# How do I replace a for-loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop

In Ruby it is bad style to use for-loops. This is commonly understood.
A style guide recommended to me:
(https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout)
says:

*"Never use for, unless you know exactly why. Most of the time iterators should be used instead. for is implemented in terms of each (so you're adding a level of indirection), but with a twist - for doesn't introduce a new scope (unlike each) and variables defined in its block will be visible outside it."*

The example given is:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

#bad
for elem in arr do
  puts elem
end

# good
arr.each { |elem| puts elem }
```

I have researched and I can't find an explanation as to how to simulate a for loop that provides an iterating value I can pass to places or perform arithmetic on.
For example, with what would I replace:

```
for i in 0...size do
  puts array1[i]
  puts array2[size-1 - i]
  puts i % 2
end
```

It's easy if it's one array, but I often need the current position for other purposes.
There's either a simple solution I'm missing, or situations where **for** is required. Additionally, I hear people talk about **for** as if it is never needed. What then is their solution to this?

Can it be improved? And what is the solution, if there is one? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to iterate over a collection *and* keep track of the index, use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
fields = ["name", "age", "height"]

fields.each_with_index do |field,i|
  puts "#{i}. #{field}" # 0. name, 1. age, 2. height
end
```

Your `for i in 0...size` example becomes:

```
array1.each_with_index do |item, i|
  puts item
  puts array2[size-1 - i]
  puts i % 2
end
```

Comment: Assuming `array1` and `array2` have the same size, it's best to write this as `array2[-1 - i]` so as to avoid having to calculate `size`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget you can do cool things like this too

```
fields = ["name", "age", "height"]

def output name, idx
  puts "#{idx}. #{name}"
end

fields.each_with_index &method(:output)
```

Output

```
0. name
1. age
2. height
```

---

You can use this technique as a class or instance method too

```
class Printer
  def self.output data
    puts "raw: #{data}"
  end
end

class Kanon < Printer
  def initialize prefix
    @prefix = prefix
  end
  def output data
    puts "#{@prefix}: #{data}"
  end
end

def print printer, data
  # separating the block from `each` allows
  # you to do interesting things
  data.each &printer.method(:output)
end
```

example using class method

```
print Printer, ["a", "b", "c"]
# raw: a
# raw: b
# raw: c
```

example using instance method

```
kanon = Kanon.new "kanon prints pretty"
print kanon, ["a", "b", "c"]
# kanon prints pretty: a
# kanon prints pretty: b
# kanon prints pretty: c
```

Comment: You could, but why would you? What does this really add?

Comment: It separates the block from the `each*` iterating. This means you can keep block wherever you want; it could be a class or instance method, it could be a dynamic proc, etc. Just demonstrating some flexibility seeing as though the OP seems to be relatively green. Having received +2, already, I don't think I'm the only one that finds this useful, too.

Comment: I agree that it's useful, but that doesn't make it relevant or on-topic. This isn't useful in the situation the question describes.

Comment: Demonstrating how to separate blocks from traditional `for-in` loops seems relevant to "How do I replace a for-loop in Ruby?" But you're the one with 56,000+ rep, so I suppose I shouldn't have bothered answering.

Comment: meagar's said what i would - this isn't relevant or on-topic.